# Cannot write to log - pig error in local mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Folks

I am new to hadoop eco system , was trying to install pig .
got stuck with the below error will trying to execute the tutorial script.
while installing the pig in hadoop cluster i did not change any permission
please let me know if have to do or the below is pertain to that.
any information is highly appreciable

```
2016-01-08 07:19:20,655 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.Main - Cannot write to 

log file: /usr/lib/pig-0.6.0/tutorial/scripts/pig_1452266360654.log
2016-01-08 07:19:20,723 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.Main - Cannot write to log file: /usr/lib/pig-0.6.0/tutorial/scripts//script1-hadoop.pig1452266360723.log
2016-01-08 07:19:20,740 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. null
2016-01-08 07:19:20,747 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.Main - There is no log file to write to.
2016-01-08 07:19:20,747 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
    at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:143)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:373)
```

Comment: Can you give us more information on what you are doing exactly? Do you want to set up Hadoop from the scratch or do you install Pig as part of a distribution?

From the urls it looks like the first... Most likely the pig process has no write rights to /usr/lib/pig-0.6.0/tutorial/scripts/

Also if you check the url there are two slashes

Comment: already configured hadoop in the machine ,trying to install the pig and run some basic tutorial script . when i try to hit the pig command while my hadoop is up and running  in the terminal . it gives a info logger level error that it cant write log file and what ever the default path i am in . it does connects to the hadoop during the initial startup.